Mulesoft Snowflake Connector Parameterized Queries
In Mulesoft Anypoint studio, how do I reference the input parameters in the SQL string (refer to screenshot)? I have tried using #[payload.x], but that does not get interpolated and results in an error. Not sure what the correct syntax to use is.

For convenience, this is the SQL String:
INSERT INTO adoit_capability_relationships ("capabilityId", "itemType", "itemId", "itemName", "dataLoadDate") VALUES(capabilityId, itemType, itemId, itemName, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());

And here are the input parameters I am trying to use:
{
    "capabilityId": payload.capabilityId,
    "itemType": payload.itemType,
    "itemId": payload.itemId,
    "itemName": payload.itemName,
    "dataLoadDate": "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()"
}


Using :param_name and INSERT INTO ... SELECT:
INSERT INTO adoit_capability_relationships 
            ("capabilityId", "itemType", "itemId", "itemName", "dataLoadDate") 
SELECT :capabilityId, :itemType, :itemId, :itemName, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();


Thank you, that worked.
